# Using MS Graph to retrieve OneNote Notebook sectionGroups returns 504 timeout

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

The notebook is in a document library on a sharepoint site.

API DOC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onenote-list-sectiongroups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/onenote/notebooks/{notebook-id}/sectionGroups](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/onenote/notebooks/%7Bnotebook-id%7D/sectionGroups)

my site id is a comma separated list of Domain, Site Collection ID, and the Site ID

I have verified the site-id and notebook-id several times. If fact, this query works fine and even returns the URL for the sectionGroups (in its response) if I drop the "/sectionGroups" from the URL.

ex. GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/onenote/notebooks/{notebook-id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/onenote/notebooks/%7Bnotebook-id%7D)

I have check for known outages and dont see anything.

The notebook only has 2 section groups in it, I have tried to limit the response by adding "?&select=displayName" to the end.

/sections also gives 504

Am I missing something in my request. I have tried executing it via a logic-app and via Graph Explorer.

should I be using the OneNote API directly?

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/onenote/notebooks/{notebook-id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/onenote/notebooks/%7Bnotebook-id%7D)

provides me a valid response for my notebook.

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/onenote/notebooks/{notebook-id}/sectionGroups](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/onenote/notebooks/%7Bnotebook-id%7D/sectionGroups)

provides me a 504 error

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/onenote/notebooks/{notebook-id}/sections](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/onenote/notebooks/%7Bnotebook-id%7D/sections)

provides me a 504 error

Comment: I have been doing more testing and it seems POST request will work to create a sectiongroup, i just can't seem to list with GET request.